# How to shift frames on time line for one of objects on curve animation

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have two objects on a curve animation. One is duplicated of other.
When I change timeline both of them move along the curve on top of each other.
But I want to shift frames for one of them so one of them should be 5 frames ahead other one for example.

Comment: so your object have a Follow Path constraint? You can use the Offset value of the constraint to shift the object

Comment: yes you are right but I can not find where to change offset property :(

Comment: what solution have you found? Did you click on the Animate Path button?

Comment: Might pay to clarify how you have set up "curve animations" .  Changing the offset as suggested or answered below will keep a constant distance offset between the dupes, whereas to time (frame) offset the same animation would consider using the NLA or drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Moonboots (Superman) said, you can do it like this:

1. add a cube, duplicate it, add a bezierpath circle

[image]

2. add follow path as object constraint and keyframe the offset value:

[image]

-> of course different for each cube

result:

[image]

Comment: Blender is such a B.